# Spa hot towel user authentication module?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application, hottowel

I installed hot towel template. However, unlike the built-in spa template, there is no log in code. Can I create an empty project using visual studio built in spa template and copy the login code over?

I want to use the external login code to login facebook.

Comment: @EvanLarsen I actually want to use the build in external login (facebook)

Comment: any login your heart desires.  Hot towel is on asp.net and is customizable.  Any authentication scenario that works in the browser and w/ asp.net will work w/ hot towel.  Its that simple.

Comment: @EvanLarsen, thanks. Maybe it's easier to create a project using the built-in spa template and then use nuget to add the hot towel files?

Answer (score 5):

I think "single page app" is often mistaken for a "single page project".  A SPA means that you can have a complete usable app in one page.  However, your project (or deployed ASP.Net application) still can have many pages.

Hence you can continue to use the built-in authentication goodies from the standard template. Just put your SPA page in a folder with a web.config containing the appropriate authentication deny=? and the Asp.net membership provider will take care of things for you.

Answer (score 1):

Someone created a sample project w/ some authentication. I haven't looked at it but it might be of interest to you. http://github.com/jamesc88/Durandal_Serverside_Authentication